# Erro ao armazenar byte na db mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

estou tentando armazenar que recebo na db mysql, porem esta dando esse erro creio que seja type da coluna erro:

> ```
> 26/02/2018 09:25:14 User connected
> 26/02/2018 09:25:14 Login : Skell
> 26/02/2018 09:25:14 Error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>    at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>    at System.Byte.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>    at System.Convert.ToByte(String value)
>    at libcomservice.Game.inventory.GetInventoryInfo(Session PLAYER) in D:\SkelletonX\GC\GC IV GC Nexus 2018\GameServer\Server\Request\Tables\Inventory.cs:line 101
> ```

linha 101 do meu code:

```
RequiredLevel = Convert.ToByte(DBAcess_0.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RequiredLevel"].ToString()), //?
```

na minha tabela tem uma coluna 'RequiredLevel' o type dela eu coloquei como
blob, porem mesmo assim da erro. Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Tente usando o [`Encoding.GetBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DBAcess_0.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RequiredLevel"].ToString());
```

[Nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072742/4551469) você pode ver um exemplo de uso do *Encoding*, convertendo para `byte[]` e de volta para `string`.

Comment: e na data type da coluna  eu deixo como blob ?

Comment: acredito que não tem problema. Como você tem um array de bytes, pode salvá-lo em uma "coluna _blob_"

Comment: @Guilherme, deu certo?!